# Xterm configuration: colors work, font size not?

Tags: terminal, fonts, xterm, dpi, high-dpi

`echo $TERM` replies `xterm-256color` and my `.Xresources` file looks like this:

```
*dpi: 165                                                       
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.autohint: false
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
XTerm*renderFont: true
XTerm*faceName: Liberation Mono 
XTerm*faceSize: 12
*background: rgb:00/00/00
*foreground: rgb:ff/ff/ff
*color0:     rgb:00/00/00
*color1:     rgb:d3/62/65
*color2:     rgb:ae/ce/91
*color3:     rgb:e7/e1/8c
*color4:     rgb:7a/7a/b0
*color5:     rgb:96/3c/59
*color6:     rgb:41/81/79
*color7:     rgb:be/be/be
*color8:     rgb:66/66/66
*color9:     rgb:ef/81/71
*color10:    rgb:e5/f7/79
*color11:    rgb:ff/f7/96
*color12:    rgb:41/86/be
*color13:    rgb:ef/9e/be
*color14:    rgb:71/be/be
*color15:    rgb:ff/ff/ff
```

While `*dpi` for example is recognize by Firefox and other applications and the color configurations do work (background is black, foreground white, ...), the font settings do not work.

Special characters like `~` look weird and font face & size do not get recognized. The font looks a bit like the default system tty's.

However, when I manually change the settings, the freshly opened terminal recognizes font face & size settings:

```
xterm -fa VeraMono -fs 12
```

Additionally, this new terminal also recognizes the `*dpi: 165` setting: fontSize 12 looks big.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it displaying the correct font ? a few suggestions: try removing the `xterm` parts. try adding a `*boldfont: ` part. try adding a `*font:` part. try using a font name that doesn't have a space ?

Comment: It was the terminal itself. Somehow the default terminal of `i3` just ignores `antialias` and other settings that make special characters look weird. I altered the `i3` config to always launch [urxvt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rxvt-unicode) (instead of the default setting) and this terminal emulator does accept/apply all settings correctly.